# Como puedo sumar los valores de un diccionario anidado e imprimir el valor mayoritario?

Tags: python, diccionarios, sum, clase-anidada, typeerror

#me pidieron sacar el producto mas vendido por lo cual recorri el dicionario en donde se almacenan las ventas e intente sumar los valores de los productos que estan guardados en otro dicionario, para despues usar Max() y sacar el producto mas vendido, el problema es que lo he intentado de diferentes maneras y en todas me da error de TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable por lo cual no se como poder hacerlo

```
    lista = {1: {'fecha': '12/4/2020', 'cliente': 120, 'productos': {34: 6, 45: 10}, 
    'vendedor': 'migue', 'precios': {34: 500, 45: 2000}}, 2: {'fecha': '13/4/2022', 
    'cliente': 1234, 'productos': {23: 4, 45: 2}, 'vendedor': 'andre', 'precios': {23: 1800, 
    45: 2000}}}

    for f in lista:

    j = lista[f]['productos']
    print(j)
```

`he intentado sumar los dicionarios pero no lo consigo lo que mejor he consegido hacer es obtener la suma de uno de las clases de esta forma

```
    def valorMayoritario(l):
        b = []
        f = 1
        for i in lista:
            a = lista[f]['productos']
            b.append([k for j,k in a.items() if j == l])
            f = f + 1

        m = []
        for i in b:
            m.append(i[0])
            n = sum(m)
        return n

    valorMayoritario(45)
```

pero aun no se como poder hacerlo en todo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
total_ventas = {}
for f in lista:
    for producto, ventas in lista[f]['productos'].items():
        if producto in total_ventas:
            total_ventas[producto] += ventas
        else:
            total_ventas[producto] = ventas

print(total_ventas)
print(max(total_ventas, key=total_ventas.get))
```

En cada iteración extras una venta (un diccionario), que consta de varios productos, los que recorres obteniendo llave y valor con un `for` sobre los `items()`.

Teniendo el código del producto y las unidades vendidas, los puedes incorporar/sumar al diccionario que lleva los totales.

Si aplicas `max()` sobre un diccionario, extraes la mayor de las llaves, pero si le pasas el `key=` le dices que valor usar para ordenar. En este caso, pasas `total_ventas.get`, un método de la clase `dictionary` que recibe una llave y devuelve una valor, que se usará para el orden.

#### Demo

```
lista = {1: {'fecha': '12/4/2020', 'cliente': 120, 'productos': {34: 6, 45: 10},
             'vendedor': 'migue', 'precios': {34: 500, 45: 2000}}, 2: {'fecha': '13/4/2022',
             'cliente': 1234, 'productos': {23: 4, 45: 2},
             'vendedor': 'andre', 'precios': {23: 1800, 45: 2000}}}

total_ventas = {}
for f in lista:
    for producto, ventas in lista[f]['productos'].items():
        if producto in total_ventas:
            total_ventas[producto] += ventas
        else:
            total_ventas[producto] = ventas

print(total_ventas)
print(max(total_ventas, key=total_ventas.get))
```

produce:

```
{34: 6, 45: 12, 23: 4}
45

Process finished with exit code 0
```